# change the value of double pointer with indirection(dereference) operator cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, double-pointer, multiple-indirection

I have problem in this sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 1, j = 2 ; 
    int **ipp = malloc(10); 
    int *ip1 = &i, *ip2= &j ;  

    ipp = &ip1;  
    // when I comment above line and uncomment this two lines
    // get segmentation fault  
    // *ipp = ip1 ;
    // **ipp = 3; 

    printf("ipp: %p %p %d \n",ipp,*ipp , **ipp);
    printf("ip1:    %p %d \n",ip1,*ip1 );
    printf("ip2:    %p %d \n",ip2,*ip2);
    printf("i:         %d \n",i);
    printf("j:         %d \n",j);
    return 0 ;
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me.

Comment: `*ipp = ip1;` should just assign the same value as you assigned in `ipp = &ip1;` so I can't see how that can cause a segfault and `**ipp = 3;` should assign 3 to `i` so that should be ok too. The only thing wrong that I can see is that the argument to `%p` should be `void*` so cast the pointers to `void*`.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Are you sure this is the *exact* code  you're running?